# Looping query result by user id and totalling in spreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet within a php script that selects data from a mysql query.

The query works and my below script works in the sense that it inserts my entire result set into my spreadsheet like so:

[image]

The only thing I can't figure out is how to modify the array loop so that I can sum totals of the 4 columns (C,D,E and F) by user. Essentially, it needs to realize that it's at the last record for user ID 48 so I can insert a row of totals, and move to the next user.

I feel it should be fairly straightforward but I just can't seem to make sense of it right now. The only other factor is that when this query runs, every user could have up to 5 records so I can use the USER ID to associate a user but the records would hinge on the ID as well as the Date, if that makes sense.

How can I get this to group by user and total their numbers before writing the info for the next user?

```
        $sql = "
            select 
             concat(u.first_name, '  ', u.last_name) as Name,
             t.ext_id as ID,
             t.total_talk_time_minutes as TalkTime,
             t.total_outbound as Outbound,
             t.total_inbound as Inbound,
             t.dealers_contacted as Dealers,
             t.date_of_report as Date
            From
                ambition.ambition_totals t
            INNER JOIN
                ambition.ambition_users u
            ON 
                t.extension = u.extension
            where
                date_of_report 
            between
                curdate() - interval 5 day and curdate()"  or die(mysqli_error( $conn));


            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


            $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
            $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

            $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Name');
            $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'User ID');
            $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Talk Time Per Call');
            $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Outbound Calls');
            $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Inbound Calls');
            $sheet->setCellValue('F1', 'Dealer Contacts');
            $sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'Date');

            $rowNumber = 2;

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
              {
                $col = 'A';

                foreach($row as $cell){
                    $sheet -> setCellValue($col.$rowNumber, $cell);
                    $col++;
                }

                $rowNumber++;
            }
```

Comment: You should first add an ORDER BY clause.